# Dragon shifters turning into humanoids or other dragons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power

I just got my hands on the *Spheres of Power* book.

Am I reading it correctly that as a first level shifter, everyone, even a dragon (or a taininim), could turn himself into a humanoid (of the same size)?

Thus, a small dragon could turn someone into a gnome or a dog. But a gnome or dog who can still breath fire and fly?

And later on they could turn themselves or others into a (different) dragon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** if you spent your initial 2 Magic Talents on Anthropomorphic Transformation and Animalistic Transformation.

Learning Anthropomorphic Transformation lets your turn into humanoids. There is simply no rule that says that this depends in any way on your original creature type (Blank Form is the only one that has such a dependency), so the fact that you're a dragon doesn't impede this. Anthropomorphic Transformation also lets you keep your old form's natural attacks, special abilities, and movement types; at the cost of not adding other Alteration traits.

So yes, you can be a gnome that flies and breathes fire. Though your gnome probably has visible wings/claws/etc, because it says "in essence making the target a hybrid", and because there are mechanical differences between wing-based and levitation-based flight so switching wouldn't quite be "retaining your movement type".

Learning Animalistic Transformation lets your turn into land animals or land magical beasts. Any trait may be granted to any form, so the "keep your old abilities" trait granted by Anthropomorphic Transformation can apply here too. So yes, you can be a dog that flies and breathes fire.

Just having the Alteration sphere gives you Blank Form, which functions as a disguise within your existing creature type and size category; in your case you can disguise yourself as other colors of dragon. If you spend a Talent on Dragon Transformation, then you
 can actually gain the abilities of other species of dragon.

Comment: what is it with the size change ability page 13 then? would that mean then......ok antrhromorphic allows you to transform into a normal human (even though you were a giant before) and with size change in addition you can be a giant human ?

Comment: If you don't have Size Change, then you can't change size. A giant with Anthropomorphic and not Size Change can pick "human" as the desired species... but they'll end up as an enlarged human, not actually medium sized.